# Flutter - Disable Bottom Navigation Bar Animation (growing text)

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I want to disable the Bottom Navigation Bar animation for selected item to get the same text/icon size of unselected items.

That's my code:

```
 class BottomNavigationBarHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black38,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(BalanceIcon.scale_balance, size: 15.0),
              title: Text('Item 1', style: TextStyle(

              ),)
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(BalanceIcon.scale_balance),
              title: Text('Item 2')
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(BalanceIcon.scale_balance),
              title: Text('Item 3')
          ),
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

I have already tried setting the same font size, the animation is still here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try add ***type*** to BottomNavigationBar

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!

Comment: This isn't the correct answer. You need to also set selectedFontSize: xx,
    unselectedFontSize: xx, as in the below answer.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers are correct but you need a combination of both, fixed type and defined font sizes:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    selectedFontSize: 12.0,
    unselectedFontSize: 12.0,
    ...
)
```

`BottomNavigationBarType.fixed` prevents the items from moving horizontally and makes the labels of the unselected items visible.

`selectedFontSize: 12.0, unselectedFontSize: 12.0` prevents the font size change when selecting an item that happens even if the type is fixed.

To re-add the gap between icon and label that disappears with this configuration, you can add a bottom padding to the icons in your `BottomNavigationBarItem`:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.5),
    child: <your icon>,
  ),
  label: <your title>,
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Add selectedFontSize & unselectedFontSize  in `BottomNavigationBar` and set the same font sizes

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedFontSize: 15.0,
        unselectedFontSize: 15.0,
```

Comment: not working, this seems working just for animation type (sliding, fixed, ecc). Even with fixed there's the text grow

Comment: as I already said in the question, I have already tried setting the same font size and is still not working